# Register implemented methods in c++

Tags: c++, game-engine, implementation

I'm writing a game engine in C++. Right now I have a class called `GameListener`, which has some game-state callback methods(like `update()`, `start()`, `awake()`). So a `GameObject` should implement either of them to actually be a `GameObject`. This is very much like Unity3D.

The problem is, however, whether a `GameObject` implements a certain method or not, it is called by the engine. So I can end up with a bunch of blank methods essentially doing nothing. How can I avoid this? Somehow register all the methods that has been implemented and call them.
In my gameloop I have something like this(pseudocode):

```
for all gamelisteners do:
gamelistener.awake();
gamelistener.update();
gamelistener.another_some_callback_method();
...
```

This is not a problem, if I have some small amount of gamelisteners and callback methods. But what if I have, say, 200 gamelisteners and 10 callback methods in GameListener interface. Not all gamelisteners implement all of these 10 callback methods, so, again, I end up with a bunch of blank methods, that are called in a gameloop.

I heard that in C# this somehow can be solved with reflections(see what methods have been actually implemented, and call only them). How can I solve this in c++?

Comment: With [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you could use [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) & [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). But your question is too broad or unclear.

Comment: Do you know that doing nothing is too costly, or are you assuming it will be? You might be trying to optimize too early.

Comment: `So a GameObject should implement either of them to actually be a GameObject` ---> do you mean "either" or "all"

Comment: measure your results when you implement all and compare it to when you don't. Is there a significant difference?

Comment: Is your purpose to improve performance by not calling unnecessary functions, or is your purpose to reduce the amount of code that is (auto-?)generated?  I'm not sure why you need to solve this problem.  Note that reflection in C# could allow you to eliminate calls by checking whether a method is implemented or not, but reflection is close to 1000 times slower than a normal method call, so you could call all of the empty methods on each of 200 objects using C++ in the time it took to check whether the first method exists on the first object and call it in C#.

Comment: @MattJordan my purpose is to improve performance. Is it not a performance drawback, when I have `n` empty method calls? (`n` can be as  big as you want) Or there's no other way around?

Comment: Since these are sub-classed methods, they will require virtual table lookup overhead; I don't think lambdas will help, they would require that the game engine provides the implementation - I suspect you want the GameListener to determine what gets called instead, as part of the expandability of the game engine.  I don't see a way to completely avoid the problem you have explained, so my advice is to try to minimize the number of callbacks as much as possible, and accept the overhead; even 20000 calls shouldn't be bad for e.g. a 4-core mobile CPU.  Have you profiled to see if this is a problem?

Comment: @MattJordan Not yet. But there's an article on this topic at unity3d blog. it is  though aimed at c# users. [link](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/)

Comment: I also think that the function call overhead might be overrated. If this is a real problem (it can indeed if you have millions of objects), I suggest separate registering of objects depending on which callback they implement. The manager class e.g. has a list of objects which are interested in callbacks when updating the screen. For this, define an abstract base class ("interface") for each kind of callback, in this case `UpdateCallback`. Then, only objects implementing this callback are involved in the loop, however, their function call is still polymorphic which *could* be optimized further.

Comment: If you have millions of objects, but only a couple of concrete subclasses, you can also maintain a registration list for each subclass and eliminate the polymorphic calls. But I guess this would require either some redundant code, highly templated code or macro hacking (your choice...), and independent of the method the manager class / main loop would require to include all headers involved, and listing all the types *somewhere*, hoping that you never forget to add a new class here.

Answer (score 0):

One implementation i have is that I have struct of function pointers that the "implementer" (in your case GameObject ) should implement and register those function pointers to the main framework(GameEngine).

So, if implementer registers a nullptr for a particular callback, then the framework should skip intimating this implementer about this event.

On the other hand, if you have mandatory callback that needs to be implemented, then the Gameengine should not allow the Gameobject to be registered with it unless it implements those..

```
using callback_defn1 = std::function<void()>;
using callback_defn2 = std::function<void(int)>;

struct gameengine_callbacks {
   callback_defn1 mandatory_callback1;
   callback_defn1 mandatory_callback2;
   callback_defn2 optional_callback1;
};
```

And on GameEngine something like

```
void GameEngine::register_objects(gameengine_callbacks callbacks)
{
   if (callbacks.mandatory_callback1 == nullptr or  callbacks.mandatory_callback1 == nullptr)
   {
         throw std::invalid_argument("some msg");
   }
   // Proceed with your registration.
}
```